# 2019 Failed to call to new PHPMailer that does not create an instance of PHPMailer Version 6.0.7

Tags: phpmailer

Failed to call new PHPMailer and does not create an instance of PHPMailer. The setting of $mail->SMTPDebug creates a stdClass instance, and then calling a non-existent method on it (isSMTP) fails. So it's all down to that instance creation failure.   PHPMailer Version 6.0.7  Live Hosting Service

I have tried $mail = new stdClass();
or $mail = NULL;  This is symptom fix but does not the cause and causes my page to send an email every time it loads.

```
 <?php 
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
    require 'PHPMailer/Exception.php';
    require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';
    require 'PHPMailer/SMTP.php';


    if(isset($_POST[‘submit’]))

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2; // 0 = off (for production use) - 1 = client messages - 2 = client and server messages
    $mail->isSMTP(); 

    $mail->Host = 'mail.email.org'; 
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; <-- Recommend by the hosting service 
    $mail->Port = 465; <-- Recommend by the hosting service <--Hosting Service Docs verify this
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'Mail@email.org';
    $mail->Password = 'Using the correct Password'; 


    $to = 'Mail@email.org'; <-- sending this to myself
    $from = 'Mail@email.org'; <--sending to myself


    $first_name = ((isset($_POST['FirstName']))&&(!is_null($_POST['FirstName'])))? $_POST['FirstName']:'';
    $last_name = ((isset($_POST['LastName']))&&(!is_null($_POST['LastName'])))? $_POST['LastName']:'';
    $email = ((isset($_POST['Email']))&&(!is_null($_POST['Email'])))? $_POST['Email']:'';
    $age = ((isset($_POST['Age']))&&(!is_null($_POST['Age'])))? $_POST['Age']:'';
    $student = ((isset($_POST['Student']))&&(!is_null($_POST['Student'])))? $_POST['Student']:'';
    $agree18 = ((isset($_POST['Agree18']))&&(!is_null($_POST['Agree18'])))? $_POST['Agree18']:'';


   /* Set the mail sender. */
    $mail->setFrom( $to , 'Research');

   /* Add a recipient. */
    $mail->addAddress( $_POST['Email'] , 'Research');
   /* Set the subject. */
    $mail->Subject = 'Learn More about Research Requested';

    $mail->isHTML(TRUE);
    $mail->Body = '<html> "First Name:" . $first_name . " Last Name:" . $last_name .  " Email:". $email . " Age:" . $age . " Student:" . $student . " Agree18:" . $agree18 . ""
</html>';


    $mail->AltBody = ' "First Name:" . $first_name . " Last Name:" . $last_name .  " Email:". $email . " Age:" . $age . " Student:" . $student . " Agree18:" . $agree18 . ""
';  

    if($mail->send()){

      $msg="Your email msg has been send";


    }else{

       $msg="mail msg has not been send"; 
       echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
     }
    ?>
```

Hope to find a solution to why it's failing.

Removed all my code, Performed what synchro stated and got this:

object(PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer)#1 (74) { ["Priority"]=> NULL ["CharSet"]=> string(10) "iso-8859-1" ["ContentType"]=> string(10) "text/plain" ["Encoding"]=> string(4) "8bit" ["ErrorInfo"]=> string(0) "" ["From"]=> string(14) "root@localhost" ["FromName"]=> string(9) "Root User" ["Sender"]=> string(0) "" ["Subject"]=> string(0) "" ["Body"]=> string(0) "" ["AltBody"]=> string(0) "" ["Ical"]=> string(0) ""
["MIMEBody":protected]=> string(0) "" ["MIMEHeader":protected]=> string(0) "" ["mailHeader":protected]=> string(0) "" ["WordWrap"]=> int(0) ["Mailer"]=> string(4) "mail" ["Sendmail"]=> string(18) "/usr/sbin/sendmail" ["UseSendmailOptions"]=> bool(true) ["ConfirmReadingTo"]=> string(0) "" ["Hostname"]=> string(0) "" ["MessageID"]=> string(0) "" ["MessageDate"]=> string(0) "" ["Host"]=> string(9) "localhost" ["Port"]=> int(25)
"Helo"]=> string(0) "" ["SMTPSecure"]=> string(0) "" ["SMTPAutoTLS"]=> bool(true) ["SMTPAuth"]=> bool(false) ["SMTPOptions"]=> array(0) { } ["Username"]=> string(0) "" ["Password"]=> string(0) "" ["AuthType"]=> string(0) "" ["oauth":protected]=> NULL ["Timeout"]=> int(300) ["dsn"]=> string(0) "" ["SMTPDebug"]=> int(0) ["Debugoutput"]=> string(4) "html" ["SMTPKeepAlive"]=> bool(false) ["SingleTo"]=> bool(false)
["SingleToArray":protected]=> array(0) { } ["do_verp"]=> bool(false) ["AllowEmpty"]=> bool(false) ["DKIM_selector"]=> string(0) "" ["DKIM_identity"]=> string(0) "" ["DKIM_passphrase"]=> string(0) "" ["DKIM_domain"]=> string(0) "" ["DKIM_copyHeaderFields"]=> bool(true) ["DKIM_extraHeaders"]=> array(0) { } ["DKIM_private"]=> string(0) "" ["DKIM_private_string"]=> string(0) "" ["action_function"]=> string(0) ""
"XMailer"]=> string(0) "" ["smtp":protected]=> NULL ["to":protected]=> array(0) { } ["cc":protected]=> array(0) { } ["bcc":protected]=> array(0) { } ["ReplyTo":protected]=> array(0) { } ["all_recipients":protected]=> array(0) { } ["RecipientsQueue":protected]=> array(0) { } ["ReplyToQueue":protected]=> array(0) { } ["attachment":protected]=> array(0) { } ["CustomHeader":protected]=> array(0) { }
"lastMessageID":protected]=> string(0) "" ["message_type":protected]=> string(0) "" ["boundary":protected]=> array(0) { } ["language":protected]=> array(0) { } ["error_count":protected]=> int(0) ["sign_cert_file":protected]=> string(0) "" ["sign_key_file":protected]=> string(0) "" ["sign_extracerts_file":protected]=> string(0) "" ["sign_key_pass":protected]=> string(0) "" ["exceptions":protected]=> bool(false) ["uniqueid":protected]=> string(0) ""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a duplicate of [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56465298/2019-phpmailer-6-07-php-scrip-how-to-send-an-email-working-example) with a different title.

When you have code that doesn't work, cut it back to a minimal example so that you exclude opportunities for ambiguity, and enable verbose, visible error reporting:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
var_dump($mail);
```

If that doesn't work, a more complex script isn't going to work either. For this to fail, I would suspect that there is something severely wrong with your PHP installation, and at the very least I would expect to see some warnings logged.

Comment: No SMTP FILE Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP' not found in /PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php:1759 Stack trace: #0 /PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php(1884): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->getSMTPInstance() #1 /PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php(1797): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->smtpConnect(Array) #2 l/PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php(1539): PHPMailer\PHPMailer PHPMailer->smtpSend('Date: Tue, 11 J...', '<html> "First N...') #3 /PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php(1375): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->postSend() #4 (69): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->send() #5 {main} thrown in PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php on line 1759

Comment: That’s actually a positive sign relative to your other script! Try adding the SMTP `use` statement and the `require` for it too.

Comment: Would I need to add a use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;?  Cause I did not in the Org code.

Comment: I add the use SMTP line and it seems like it worked. I did not know that was required but all my error went away and it made the connection and sent.  I am not sure if thats the fix?  I will play around with it and confirm.

Comment: Strictly speaking you don’t need the `use` statement for the SMTP class because it’s never referred to directly in your code. You will need the `require` though. Glad it worked for you; if this answer helped you solve the issue, please mark this answer as such (click the check mark).

Comment: I will work on this and confirm it and will give you credit where credit is due for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a bracket after condition with `isset($_POST[...])`.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //                      ^^
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2; // 0 = off (for production use) - 1 = client messages - 2 = client and server messages
    $mail->isSMTP(); 
    ...
}
// of course, don'f forget to add a closing one too here.
```

Comment: The issue is when I add the {}, it does not send any emails to me. If I remove it and add the $mail = new stdClass();
or $mail = NULL; , It emails me.  If I do both, it does not email me. Already redownloaded the PHPMailer Files as well with no change.

Comment: @TD00: brackets are correctly in there. So check if there is any input/button with `name=submit` in your form. If so, you have used bad quotes around the key. It has to be `$_POST['submit']` not `$_POST[‘submit’]` (I've good ones quotes in my answer).

Comment: Both of these things came up in [the original question discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194612/discussion-on-question-by-td00-2019-phpmailer-6-07-php-scrip-how-to-send-an-em).

Comment: @Synchro: really don't check the chat, working just with info&codes published here in question.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed <-- ***Thanks to Synchro*** -->  & Thanks Panthers for the input

Added use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP; <- This fixed most of my issues but not always required per Synchro

For working example with PHPMailer 6.0.7 look for Synchro's
This is a duplicate of your previous question with a different title Link.